# Creating jqplot graph using php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jqplot

I want to display a date chart using data from mysql. I use the library jqplot to generate graph. Chart should have a date on the X axis, on Y axis some numeric values.

MySQL

In MySQL i have pool: ID, Temperature, Date

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temperature_monitor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `temperature` float NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `counter_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT= 4 ;
```

Date from mysql i put in array using php

```
$date = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = array(
        "date"  => $row['date'],
        "temperature"   => $row['temperature']
    );
    $date_array[] = $date;

}

echo ('['.json_encode($date_array).']');
```

This is a script showing chart

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "temperature.php", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: 'json', 

    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json);

        var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart3', [json], {
            title:'Customized Date Axis',
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'},
                    min:'2016-03-01',
                    tickInterval:'1 day'
                }
            },
            series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
        });

    },
    error:function (json){
    }
});});
```

The data to the show chart should be in format: [['2008-08-12 4:00PM',4],[.......,...],........]

Example from documentation:

```
`var line1=[['2008-08-12 4:00PM',4], ['2008-09-12 4:00PM',6.5], ['2008-10-12 4:00PM',5.7], ['2008-11-12 4:00PM',9], ['2008-12-12 4:00P`M',8.2]];
```

When I get data from mysql unfortunately, generates a blank chart without any values.

I don't know what is wrong.

> SOLVED:

Code php should be change on

```
    $date = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = array($row['date'],$row['temperature']);
    $date_array[] = $date;

}

echo (json_encode($date_array));
```